# Error UnassignedReferenceException keeps popping up when connecting animation to movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a new programmer making a top down 2d game in Unity with c# and I keep getting the error:

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable animator of PlayerMovement has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the animator variable of the PlayerMovement script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.Animator.SetFloat (System.String name, System.Single value) (at <049be2afe36f487eb06ef49d51a0bab6>:0)
PlayerMovement.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:23)

I don't know what this means, but I figure that I haven't properly assigned the variable of PlayerMovement to something? Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;

    Vector2 movement;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Input
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        movement = movement.normalized;

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Movement and physics
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: are `animator` and `rb` referenced via the Inspector?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an object reference to call the method [SetFloat()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html). You have to instance the `Animator` object in the Start method to avoid this Exception:

```
void Start()
    {
        //Get the animator, which you attach to the GameObject you are intending to animate.
        animator= gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    });
```

Comment: well unless OP drags it into the `public` field via the Inspector ...